# select distinct from a union table with one column as preference

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a result of a union of two tables like this:

```
UserId  AppId   Status
------------------------
A1      5       INACTIVE
A1      5       SUSPENDED
A1      6       REVOKED
A1      6       SUSPENDED
A1      6       ACTIVE
A1      7       REVOKED
A1      8       SUSPENDED
B2      7       INACTIVE
B2      7       INACTIVE
B2      7       ACTIVE
C3      6       INACTIVE
```

How can I eliminate the rows with duplicate UserId and AppId and return with just one Status, with an order of preference to return:
1. ACTIVE
2. SUSPENDED
3. REVOKED
4. INACTIVE

```
UserId  AppId   Status
------------------------
A1      5       SUSPENDED
A1      6       ACTIVE
A1      7       REVOKED
A1      8       SUSPENDED
B2      7       ACTIVE
C3      6       INACTIVE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usual problem is referred to as "selecting the top row by group". The query looks something like this:

```
WITH comp AS (
    SELECT t.UserId, 
        t.AppId, 
        t.Status, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.UserId, t.AppId 
            ORDER BY CASE 
                WHEN t.Status = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1
                WHEN t.Status = 'SUSPENDED' THEN 2
                ...
            END CASE ASC) AS rank
      FROM ??? AS t)
SELECT *
  FROM comp
 WHERE rank = 1
```

For more on this topic: [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 0):

Create a table for status precedence with a column for the status, and a number between 1 and 4 like you listed in your preferences.
Join that table to your set, and use a MAX aggregate function with a GROUP BY UserId and AppId to find which highest precedence exists for each user and in turn use that as a filter.

You didn’t specify which database engine you use, and you didn’t provide DDL and sample data, so we can’t give you a working solution, just high level guidelines to get you in the right direction.

HTH